# Locking screen by z-index in windows phone

Tags: css, cordova, windows-phone-8, z-index

I use loader when app loads data, under the loader there is dark screen,
links and navigation items should be locked in that time, app is phonegap based app, and everything is ok in iOS and Android.
Problem is in WP8,the screen is dark, but links and navigation are clickable.
Here is my css code for loader

```
.loader {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:1000;
}
```

I've researched and found one solution to use transparent icon instead of rgba colorizing but it couldn't resolve the problem. Please any solution or ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried using a modal Dialog? The modal dialog will overshadow the application and prevent any clicks, while the app is loading. The modal dialog will display a message that the app is loading. Then remove the modal dialog once the app completes loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved via JavaScript.
I have added the click event listener to my loader element (.loader).

```
$(.loader).on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```