# Layers with higher z-index gets ignored by touches on Windows Phone 8 Cordova HTML5 App

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

We are porting a cordova app from iOS / Android to Windows Phone 8 and have a problem with our overlays.
The overlay is a div that has an higher z-index defined than the divs beneath and the it contains several controls (e.g. inputs). 
The problem we have is that the overlay div is ignored by touch events, instead the events on the underlying divs(which should be locked by the overlay) are fired. I tried to set -ms-touch-action:none css property to the underlying divs with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Show some code you have.

Comment: you need to catch the **touch** events in the overlay div and then use `event.preventdefault()` function in the handler that catches the **touch** events to prevent propagation of the event.

Comment: @frank It seems like there no touch event fired for the overlay at all, just for the underlying controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was the trick @frank posted in his comment. Just do

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in a click handler for the overlay. Or the angular way

```
ng-click="$event.preventDefault()".
```

Also described here: [Locking screen by z-index in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028820/locking-screen-by-z-index-in-windows-phone?rq=1)

Thanks for the help, guys, especially @frank

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that shows the fundamental markup and CSS

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlay-content">
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>... and so on...
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="page-content">
        <div>
            <div id="button" onclick="..."></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

 #overlay{
    z-index: 7000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#page-content{  
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The onclick handler of the div in 'page-content' gets fired if we touch the overlay div when its visible.